# PHP Nested While loop work only one time with mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

There are nested while loop in this question. Please check the code 01 and code 02.

**Code 01**

```
$sql2 ="select * from view";
$view_list = mysqli_query($con,$sql2); //  Assume there are 5 items

$sql ="select * from apartment";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    while ($view_row = mysqli_fetch_array($view_list, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $view_row['view_name']." , "; 
    }
    <br>
}
```

> *Result* :
>
> A,B,C,

**Code 02**

```
$sql ="select * from apartment";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    $sql2 ="select * from view";
    $view_list = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);

    while ($view_row = mysqli_fetch_array($view_list, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $view_row['view_name']." , ";  //This loop works few times  as expected
    }
    <br>
}
```

*Result* :

> A,B,C,
>
> A,B,C,
>
> A,B,C,
>
> A,B,C,
>
> A,B,C,

I thought both Code 01 and Code 2 should return same output.... But code one nested loop work only 3 times (That is for first circle of parent loop.)

So I wanted to know that why code 01 not working as I expected? That means. why code 01 and code 02 result is different?

Comment: Buddy, is there any relationship between those 2 tables?

Comment: The second version calls `mysqli_query($con,$sql2);` for each loop, therefore the result will be  returned for each iteration of the loop.  In the first sample, you reach the end of the `$view_list` result set at the end of the first iteration.

Answer (score -1):

you have to move the result internal pointer with [mysqli_data_seek](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php)
doing a while to $view_list move the internal pointer of the array forward. In the second cycle the pointer is already to the end of the array, so the script will not print anything. You have to do something similar to `mysqli_data_seek($view_list, 0)` in orther to reset the pointer

```
$sql2 ="select * from view";
$view_list = mysqli_query($con,$sql2); //  Assume there are 5 items

$sql ="select * from apartment";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    mysqli_data_seek($view_list, 0)
    while ($view_row = mysqli_fetch_array($view_list, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $view_row['view_name']." , "; 
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: It would improve this answer if you would give an example of how and where this should be done.

Comment: You should show using it in the context of the OP's code.